# Restoring GWLP_USERDATA after subclassing is no longer necessary

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a Subclass class and within it I use `SetWindowLongPtr()` to set `GWLP_USERDATA` to contain pointer to derived class which I use to distribute messages.

So if I use `SetWindowLongPtr(CurrentWindow, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)Data);`, how do I restore
the old Data when I no longer want to subclass? MSDN says that initial value is zero, so should I use `SetWindowLongPtr(CurrentWindow, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)NULL);` function?

Edit:
I actually found a way around this using SetProp, GetProp, RemoveProp, now I don't need to worry about messing up things for other functions.
Bellow is my code for those who might need it:

```
#ifndef WIN32_SUBCLASS_CLASS_H
#define WIN32_SUBCLASS_CLASS_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

class SubclassWindow
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK stWinSubclassHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        SubclassWindow* pWnd;
        pWnd = (SubclassWindow*)GetProp(hwnd, TEXT("Subclass"));

        if (pWnd)
            return pWnd->WinSubclassHandler(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        else
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    BOOL Subclass(SubclassWindow* Data, HWND hwnd)
    {
        if (Subclassed == TRUE || CurrentWindow != NULL)
            return 0;

        CurrentWindow = hwnd;
        Subclassed = TRUE;
        OriginalProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
        SetProp(CurrentWindow, TEXT("Subclass"), (HANDLE)Data);
        SetWindowLongPtr(CurrentWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassWindow::stWinSubclassHandler);

        return 1;
    }
    BOOL RemoveSubclass()
    {
        if (OriginalProc == NULL || CurrentWindow == NULL)
            return 0;

        Subclassed = FALSE;
        RemoveProp(CurrentWindow, TEXT("Subclass"));
        SetWindowLongPtr(CurrentWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)OriginalProc);

        return 1;
    }

    BOOL IsSubclassed() { return Subclassed; }
protected:
    HWND CurrentWindow;
    WNDPROC OriginalProc;
    BOOL Subclassed;

    SubclassWindow()
    {
        CurrentWindow = NULL;
        OriginalProc = NULL;
        Subclassed = FALSE;
    }

    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This is risky, it interferes with the original window using user data.  Since it apparently didn't do that, restoring it isn't necessary either.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use some logical statements to make sure it is empty before subclassing in the future.

Comment: If you don't need to support common controls prior to version 6 you don't need to mess with `GWLP_USERDATA`. The MSDN has all there is to know to subclassing: [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx).

Comment: Can't use it, because it is UNICODE only and I want my code to be for both ANSI and UNICODE

Comment: If you use `SetWindowSubclass` you don't need to worry about any of this.

Comment: @Helix You misinterpreted the documentation. The **controls** are UNICODE only and should not be subclassed with an ANSI window procedure. There's no mention that `SetWindowSubclass` and friends can only be used with UNICODE windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetWindowLongPtr()` returns the old value, so save it and then restore it when you call `SetWindowLongPtr()` later to remove the subclass.

That being said, it is dangerous to replace `GWLP_USERDATA` for a window that you did not create yourself. You don't know if the window was already using `GWLP_USERDATA` for its own purposes or not.  Use [`SetWindowSubclass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, which was designed to address that concern:

```
class SubclassWindow
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK stWinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
    {
        SubclassWindow* pWnd = (SubclassWindow*) dwRefData;    
        if ((pWnd) && (uIdSubclass == 1))
            return pWnd->WinSubclassHandler(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        else
            return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    BOOL Subclass(SubclassWindow* Data, HWND hwnd)
    {
        if (CurrentWindow != NULL)
            return FALSE;

        if (!SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, &stWinSubclassHandler, 1, (DWORD_PTR)Data))
            return FALSE;

        CurrentWindow = hwnd;
        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL RemoveSubclass()
    {
        if (CurrentWindow == NULL)
            return FALSE;

        if (!RemoveWindowSubclass(CurrentWindow, &stWinSubclassHandler, 1))
            return FALSE;

        CurrentWindow = NULL;
        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL IsSubclassed() { return (CurrentWindow != NULL); }

protected:
    HWND CurrentWindow;

    SubclassWindow()
    {
        CurrentWindow = NULL;
    }

    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;
};
```

If your derived classes need to default-process any given message, the only change you would have to make is to have their `WinSubclassHandler()` implementations call `DefSubclassProc()` instead of `DefWindowProc()` (which BTW was the wrong API to call - you should have been calling `CallWindowProc(OriginalProc, ...)` instead so the previous window procedure that your subclass replaces has a chance to process messages).  For that, I would suggest wrapping that call inside of your `SubclassWindow` class to hide that detail from descendants, eg:

```
class SubclassWindow
{
...
protected:
    ...
    static LRESULT DefaultHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    ...
};
```

```
class MySubclass : public SubclassWindow
{
protected:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ...
        return DefaultHandler(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```

Alternatively (which would allow descendants to derive from descendants better):

```
class SubclassWindow
{
...
protected:
    ...
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    ...
};
```

```
class MySubclass1 : public SubclassWindow
{
protected:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ...
        return SubclassWindow::WinSubclassHandler(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};

class MySubclass2 : public MySubclass1
{
protected:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ...
        return MySubclass1::WinSubclassHandler(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};

class MySubclass3 : public MySubclass2
{
protected:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WinSubclassHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ...
        return MySubclass2::WinSubclassHandler(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As Hans mentioned, you're not in a good shape if there's something to restore. That would mean the original `WNDPROC`, which is still being used for anything you won't process, will be expecting another value in there.

That said, [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the old value, so you can always call [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first to get the original value. That value may still be zero, but at least you'll know for sure.